# Is it possible to ignore some lines in html on building html with Gulp?

Tags: gulp

I have a html setup in my app folder and this is copied in the dist folder by gulp.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../dist/css/style.css">
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ui-view></div>

<!-- build:jsLib js/libs.js -->
<script src="../libs/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->

<!-- build:jsApp js/app.js -->
<script src="app.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->

<script src="../libs/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    angular.module('testApp', ['mockService', 'productServicesApp', 'ngMockE2E']);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

That part is used to make fake service calls and I don't want it in deployment files:

```
//something like *ignore this*
<script type="text/javascript">
        angular.module('testApp', ['mockService', 'productServicesApp', 'ngMockE2E']);
</script>
```

Is is possible to ignore this line with gulp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is possible. A nice plugin to do this would be the [gulp-remove-code](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-remove-code) plugin.

Below is an example of how you would use it

**HTML:**

```html
<div>
  <!--removeIf(production)-->
  <div class="sandbox-banner">Running in sandbox environment</div>
  <!--endRemoveIf(production)-->

  <span>Removing code is ready.</span>
</div>
```

**GULP:**

```js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var removeCode = require('gulp-remove-code');

HTML_FILES = '/path/to/html/**/*.html';

gulp.task('clean-html', function() {
  return gulp.src(HTML_FILES)
    .pipe(removeCode({ production: true }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'));
});
```

And then you just call it by saying

```
gulp clean-html
```

Anything inside of those comment tags will be removed. Also, the object passed to removeCode is not namespace specific. So you can change the naming to whatever.